# $6^x \equiv 11 \mod{17}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Here's a simple question using index notation.

> Find all incongruent solutions of the following congruence: $$6^x
> \equiv 11 \mod{17}.$$

Since $3$ is a primitive root modulo $17$, we have $$x \mathrm{ind}_{3} 6 \equiv \mathrm{ind}_3 11 \mod{16}$$ or $$15x \equiv 7 \mod{16}.$$ Hence $x \equiv -7 \equiv 9 \mod{16}$.

Here's my question: Is the congruence $x \equiv 9 \mod{16}$ enough or should this be converted to $x \equiv \, ?? \mod{17}$ somehow? Since this was the original modulo in the problem. Becuase this conversion I'm unsure how to determine.

**EDIT:** Resolved. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is worth noting that $x \equiv 9 \pmod{16}$ can have all possible $17$ remainders when divided by $17$, i.e., there exists infinite solutions $x$ such that $$x \equiv 9 \pmod{16} \equiv m \pmod{17}$$for all $m \in \{0,1,2\ldots,16\}$. Hence, leaving your answer as $x \equiv 9 \pmod{16} \in \mathbb{Z}^+$ is the best possible way to express the solution.

Answer (score 1):

It is impossible to convert a congruence of the form $x\equiv 9 \pmod {16}$ to a congruence modulo $17$.. Simply stating $$ x \equiv 9 \pmod{16}$$ should suffice (of course mention $x \ge 0$)